# Where is the color setting for disabled menu items?

Tags: customization, theme

I somehow changed to color of disabled menu items, so that they are not grayed out unless you hover over them.

As you can see, the *Search* and submenu entries should be grayed out, but are only grayed out when hovering over them.

Changed color theme on the left and, the default color theme on the right. 
[image: changed color theme] [image: default color theme]

What did I change that did this?

Comment: What do you mean? I have the default theme and those menus don't get grayed out..

Comment: @someonewithpc It's a bit tricky to do.. 1. Add a material in BI 2. switch to cycles 3. Open the BI material in the node editor and press Shift+A. It affects all disabled menu items though, so if you can find some others those will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the colors here re-use generic names (and it isn't always very logical)

See: `Menu Item -> Color -> Inner`